# Data loss in Azure Redis Cache

Tags: azure, caching

Following statement suggests that, Azure only provide SLA on Cache endpoint and not on Data.

> SLA only covers connectivity to the Cache endpoints. The SLA does not
>   cover protection from data loss.

My question is, in case of data loss, would all the data be lost from my instance. Or partial data loss is also possible. For instance if I have 2K key-value pairs, is it possible that half of the key value pair are lost.

Why I am curious, because in one application I store some processed result in case (which can be built from data stored in sql). But this data processing is time consuming. Now in case data loss happens, I will have to build this cache again. If I can be sure that whenever data is lost, all of my key-value pair will be gone and I can run this process again from scratch.

And If partial loss is possible, then while accessing individual key value pair, if I don't find it in cache, I will have to build this key-value pair.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like perhaps Redis isn't the right solution for your scenario if you care more about data loss than performance / shared state. Having said this, you could always look at [data persistence for Redis](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cache-how-to-premium-persistence/), though this requires use of the Premium tier in Azure.

Comment: Thanks Simon for quick response! My cache data is incremental. I need to update that data very frequently. 'Redis persistence' is not useful for me as I  cannot afford to lose 15 min. of data.

Comment: Given your RPO for this solution you probably want to look at using Azure SQL Database with active geo-replication which has an RPO in the ballpark you need. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-business-continuity/

Comment: Simon, When I said I cannot afford to lose 15 min. of data I mean, I cannot work with stale data but I can surely process it again (as I already have all input in my sql) and start working. But question is, would I have to process everything again (if data is lost for full instance) or if data can be lost is bits and piece, I can rebuilt it for individual key-value pair.

Comment: @Pragmatic - I suggest moving this to Chat, and not having a discussion in an answer's comments.